# TemplateDoesNotExist error in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am getting a TemplateDoesNotExist error on my django project and it is very frustrating because I have tried to make the app over and over again to but no avail. I was trying to see if I have made any noticeable errors but I cannot seem to find anything at all. I am making this project to help me learn django off of a website called [OneMonth](https://onemonth.com/).

GitHub Project Files [Here](https://github.com/Web-App-Dev/coffeedapp)

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MAIN_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'c#16w5r9r2)^n1%7@n4yp*l#itoq_&nw^%c(0f)(_0k0p2vs#w'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'coffeedapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
        {
                'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
                'DIRS': [],
                'APP_DIRS': True,
                'OPTIONS': {
                        'context_processors': [
                                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                        ],
                },
        },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'coffeedapp.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
        'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
}

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'templates'),
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'coffeedapp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'', include('core.urls')),
)
```

core/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import core.views as coreviews

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'coffeedapp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^$', coreviews.LandingView.as_view()),
)
```

Comment: Provide the full trace back show your code here and not post any github location this problem may due to placing template in the wrong location

Answer (score 1):

Found that your `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` setting is blank.

Have you tried to  declare your templates folder inside the `TEMPLATES` instead of using `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'templates'),
)`?

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: So I got it to work but i do not know if this is the correct way of doing it I

Comment: I did it the same way that you had up there but I used **BASE_DIR** instead of **MAIN_DIR** and I do not know if that Is the correct way of doing it or not???